# Keep Getting Logged Out of Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, sessions, cookies

I keep getting logged out of the control panel while I'm working in it.

Under *Admin > Security & Privacy > Security and Session Preferences*, I have:

- **Control Panel Session Type:** Cookies & Session ID
- **Require IP Address and User Agent for Login?**: Yes

I tried clearing my cookies - didn't work.

I tried setting *Require IP Address and User Agent for Login?* to "no" - didn't work.

I tried setting *Control Panel Session Type* to "cookies only" - didn't work.

What else should I try?

EE 2.5.5

Comment: I have a similar issue, but only when visiting the channel or channel fields tab, It wants me to login again. Can't find the setting or figure out what would have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main suggestion I have is setting a value for the cookie prefix and seeing if that works.

I actually had a similar problem to this on ONE site that was configured seemingly identically to some of my others, but this exact thing happened to me. This set of config items added to my main config.php seemed to alleviate it for me:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path'] = "";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "someprefix";
$config['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$config['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n";
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

The secure forms bit in particular seems to be what was causing trouble for that site, despite completely wiping out the EE core and starting fresh, though I couldn't tell you why. Probably some legacy garbage hanging around in the database.

The previous suggestion about setting configurations for the session ttl values may work also.

Comment: I think the cookie prefix actually worked. I added your config variables and haven't been booted out of the CP again. Crazy!

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I've been adding the following to my config file (based on someone else's recommendation):

```
$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 14400;
$config['user_session_ttl'] = 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced logouts while **working with multiple tabs** (sometimes up to 10 for different templates etc.). It seems that your session times out if one of the tabs "times out".